# How to remove deployed files removed from git

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I'm using Teamcity to deploy a Django application from a git repository over SCP. The problem is that whenever I git rm a file, commit and push, the file is not removed from the server. I understand that SCP copies file and doesn't remove them, that's fine. What's the canonical way to remove deleted and renamed files?